# How can I make text figures document wide standard for numerals in Context?

Tags: context, oldstylenums

In a CV I would like all numbers to be text figures. I can do this manually by using the `{\os 123}` switch locally, but I would like text figures to be the default in the document. How?

If I make it the default, can I override it in some way if I **want** titling figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the font feature `onum` (old style numbers) to the default set of
font features as follows:

```
\definefontfeature
  [default] [default]
  [onum=yes]
```

Now all number are changed. To switch back to normal numbers you can
subtract the feature within a group:

```
 {\feature[-][oldstyle] 0123456789}
```

For less clutter within the document I would suggest the more semantic approach to create a logical markup
element, e.g. `nooldstyle`. Here's a complete example:

```
\definefontfeature
  [default] [default]
  [onum=yes]

\definehighlight
  [nooldstyle]
  [style=\feature{-}{oldstyle}]

\starttext
  0123456789\par
  \nooldstyle{0123456789}\par
  0123456789
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, I already tried that. Seems like `\setupbodyfont [cmr,10pt]` is messing this up. It only works with OpenType fonts I guess? I'd like to keep using Computer modern (`cmr`) instead of Lucida bright (`lbr`).

Comment: I don't quite understand the comment about Lucida. Lucida is not used by default and doesn't even ship with ConTeXt. If you want to use Computer Modern in contrast to the default “Latin Modern” you can use an OpenType version of Computer Modern. I don't know if it contains old style figures, though.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of "Latin Modern", anyhow, if I remove `\setupbodyfont[10pt]` the old style figures work. As soon as I set the body font (even just changing size as above, text figures doesn't work. Any idea on how to change font size and still keep them?

Comment: It works for me if I add `\setupbodyfont[10pt]` before `\starttext` in my example above.

Comment: The problem for me was that I had `\setupbodyfont[10pt]` before the `\definefontfeature`... It obviously has to be the other way around, why I don't know. Now it works perfect!

Comment: The font uses up the default font features defined *at that point* where you select that font. This concept applies to ConTeXt or TeX in general. TeX doesn't look forward to check what might be defined later.